# Installing memcached on CentOS 6

Tags: memcached, centos

I have to admit to be fumbling in the dark here.  I am fairly good at PHP but I know little or nothing about managing LINUX servers.  I need to install memcached on my 64 bit CentOS 6 server and came across two very informative resources

http://boomshadow.net/tech/installs/how-to-install-memcached/

I followed the steps expained there and the memcached daemon is up and running on my server now.  I still need to install the PHP extension for memcache so I tried the steps explained here

http://boomshadow.net/tech/installs/how-to-install-php-memcache/

Here is the output I get

```
[root@xxx ~]# pecl install memcache
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update   
pecl.php.net" to update
downloading memcache-3.0.8.tgz ...
Starting to download memcache-3.0.8.tgz (70,523 bytes)
.................done: 70,523 bytes
15 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Enable memcache session handler support? [yes] : yes
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootZi8fyR/memcache-3.0.8
running: /var/tmp/memcache/configure --enable-memcache-session=yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... no
checking for gcc... no
configure: error: in `/var/tmp/pear-build-rootZi8fyR/memcache-3.0.8':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: `/var/tmp/memcache/configure --enable-memcache-session=yes' failed
[root@xxx
```

I cannot make a secret of this - most of this is Greek to me.  What I think I have figured out is that pecl is looking for a C compiler to build the PHP memcache driver from the downloaded source and cannot find it.  Even if that is right it does not help me much.

Just what do I need to do here to get things working correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Old habits die hard, I guess - answering my own question once again.

```
# yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

to install development tools including the gcc compiler.  The memcahe.so extension uses zlib so you also need to do

```
# yum install zlib-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

if you came accross configure: error: no, sasl.h is not available. Run configure with --disable-memcached-sasl to disable this check
ERROR: `/var/tmp/memcached/configure --with-libmemcached-dir=no' failed`

```
./configure --enable-memcached-sasl=no
make
make install

pecl install memcached
```